# Time zone offset select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

If there any helper or method, that could provide me with select with timezone offset, which will generate only numbers in its view, e.g.(`<option value="-6">-6</option>`)

I tried `<%= time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>`, but this provide me with only string information, which wont work for me.

P.S. I'm about to switch to options_for_select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such built-in Rails helpers, but it's easy to implement with `options_for_select`

```
options_for_select(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map {|zone| zone.utc_offset / 3600}.uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did this

```
<%= collection_select :prefix, :suffix, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :utc_offset, :name, 
      {:selected => -21600}%>
```